# Disable Code analysis warnings .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

In visual studios i can run code analysis on my .NET project. I am running basic correctness and have 85 warnings. Which is a little much. Also majority of them are in external code.

How do i disable specific warnings so i can focus on the more important warnings? I tried the below but it does not recognize code analysis warnings. (I first tried w/o the CA)

```
#pragma warning disable CA1820 CA1065 CA2100
```

Comment: lol @ "85 being a little much". I turned on a basic ruleset (errors for CA1811 and CA1823) for a windows forms app that was started in .NET 1.0, and had 490 of just those two. As a rule, code analysis and FX cop will HATE on your code, especially if you are not using them from the start.

Comment: @Stingy: I wouldn't mind it so much if it wasnt telling me to make changes i dont want to make (i'd have to check but i remember one warning saying it may be given out incorrectly and it was. Dozen of time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to copy a code analysis ruleset and disable the rules you don't like.

Go to the Project Properties, select a ruleset to start from, then click Open.
Uncheck the rules that you don't like, then click Save As.
Finally, select that rule set in Project Properties.

You can also start from scratch, by right-clicking the project or solution and clicking Add New Item, Code Analysis Rule Set.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to disable warnings on a project-wide level:

Go to project properties, the Code Analysis window, and click "Open" next to the rule set to run.  Uncheck the warnings you want to ignore, save the ruleset (probably you'll need to do a Save As since you can't modify the default rulesets), go back to the project code analysis tab, and select the ruleset you just saved.

If you just want to disable specific warnings in specific places in the code:

Use the [SuppressMessageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.aspx).